# Export download history from chrome

Tags: javascript, html, list, google-chrome, download

I use Google Chrome on Linux Debian 10. And I download many files by this (thousands). And I should to export links, I downloaded files from. I was looking for method in the Internet and found some JS-scripts, I should paste to console on [chrome://downloads/](http://chrome://downloads/) page like:

```
ditems = document.querySelector("downloads-manager").shadowRoot.querySelector("iron-list").querySelectorAll("downloads-item");

var div = document.createElement('div');

[].forEach.call(ditems, function (el) {
var br = document.createElement('br');
var hr = document.createElement('hr');
div.appendChild(el.shadowRoot.querySelector("#url"));
div.appendChild(br);
div.appendChild(hr);

});
document.body.innerHTML=""
document.body.appendChild(div);
document.head.style.innerHTML="";
```

But each from this code covered only little part of my downloads list. First, I decided It's because my big list is not loaded full, so I spent time to scroll down till the end and tried again, but nothing had changed. What should I do?
Screenshots: [1, before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPhxb.png); [2, before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYqAH.png); [1, after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/071BY.png); [2, after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGSC4.png). Such I want to say, It shows only little random part of big list.

Comment: Try to directly extract it from the downloads database. It's the 'downloads' table from Default/History.

Comment: @shkiperdesna did you find a way to export Chrome's download history?

Answer (score 2):

As @joy-jin mentioned in his comment, you can extract it from Chrome's history database.

1. Locate the `History` file:

   - on macOS: `~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/`
   - on Windows: `%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`
   - on Linux: `~/.config/google-chrome/Default`
2. Make a copy of the file `History` to another location (you can't use the original while Chrome is open).
3. Now, you can extract the download links from the copied file, either using [sqlite3](https://www.sqlite.org/) CLI, or using a GUI SQLite viewer such as [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/). The download links are in the table `downloads_url_chains`.

Similar question that contains some useful sqlite3 commands: https://superuser.com/questions/602252/can-chrome-browser-history-be-exported-to-an-html-file